# How to href an id while using module.config/ng-view?

Tags: angularjs, href, ng-view

I'm configuring an `ng-view` like follow :

```
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider", function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "views/home.html",
            controller: "homeCtrl"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "views/error.html"
        });
    }]);
```

The thing is that, now, anytime I click on something like below, it redirects me to the `error.html` page.

```
<a href="#mobile_app">Mobile</a>
```

Also, I see an empty page while it should show the `error.html` content. There is no error in the process.

How can I `href` an id in this case ? Also why is the `error.html` page not shown (even if I don't want it to be shown if the user clicks on an id, I wonder why it doesn't show) ?

Answer (score 0):

try this ,  hope solves your problem.

```
<a href="#/mobile_app">Mobile</a>
```

and in route config you must catch /mobile_app .

Comment: What do you mean by "route config you must catch /mobile_app" ? I'm not changing the view, just going to the offset of the tag with a specific id.

Comment: I mean this ,                                          .when("/mobile_app", {
            templateUrl: "views/home.html",
            controller: "homeCtrl"
        })